# Save from viewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller

I have a very small bit of data that I would like to archive from my apps view. My question is, its far easier to save this data from the viewController, but should I really be pushing it back into my model and saving it there? BTW: I also need to do a quick load of this data when the app starts up.

Comment: What? I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Not to worry, I am going to save the data via my existing save routines in the data model. I was just curious if saving data (thats not part of the model) via the viewController broke the mvc design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. If the data is not part of the model, then, no, the model classes should not take on the responsibility of saving it. If the data is only concerned with the view, then perhaps the view object should be responsible for saving, but that would break the rule that view objects should only concern themselves with display.

Seeing as we are in Cocoa territory, I think this task falls firmly to the ViewController. If you make sure that the ViewController is represented by an object (blue box, if I'm not mistaken) in Interface Builder, then you can take advantage of awakeFromNib to load your save data. BTW, it sounds like NSUserDefaults should be mechanism to use to do the archiving/saving & unarchiving/loading.